# How to install OpenBSD 7.1 on NanoPi R4S using SD card as root disk?

Tags: system-installation, openbsd, sd-card, arm64

I would like to install OpenBSD 7.1 on the [NanoPi R4S](https://wiki.friendlyelec.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_R4S) (Rockchip RK3399 ARM64 SoC).

Following the instructions in [INSTALL.arm64](http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/7.1/arm64/INSTALL.arm64), I managed to make the NanoPi R4S boot [miniroot71.img](http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/7.1/arm64/miniroot71.img). I wrote the miniroot and the OpenBSD-supplied [U-Boot images](http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/7.1/packages/aarch64/u-boot-aarch64-2021.10p3.tgz) (idbloader.img, u-boot.itb) for `nanopi-r4s-rk3399` to a 64 GB SD card using `dd`. I then mounted the EFI partition of the miniroot and copied the OpenBSD-supplied [DTB file](http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/7.1/packages/aarch64/dtb-5.14p1.tgz) `rk3399-nanopi-r4s.dtb` into the directory `/rockchip`.

Having put the SD card into the NanoPi R4S and using its debug UART, I am finally able to boot from the miniroot and start the OpenBSD installation program.

However, I get stuck as soon as I need to specify the root disk. The installer displays no choices for the root disk. Having a look at the boot messages, it seems that OpenBSD could not enable the SD card:

```
sdmmc0: can't enable card
```

I was not able to find really helpful information on this. Is it generally not possible to install OpenBSD on SD card? Is it a missing feature of the ARM64 port? Is it an issue with the SD card interface of the NanoPi R4S? Something else?

Comment: It is definitely possible to install on SD on arm64. It’s likely a driver support issue for the NanoPi R4S specifically. I would post the question on the arm@ mailing list https://www.openbsd.org/mail.html