# OpenBSD 7.2 NanoPi R4S sdmmc0: can't enable card

Tags: openbsd, sd-card, u-boot, arm64

I am facing the following issue with SD card when trying to install OpenBSD 7.2 on Nanopi R4S (Rockchip RK3399 ARM64 SoC). The same problem as [previously described on OpenBSD 7.1 here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701776/how-to-install-openbsd-7-1-on-nanopi-r4s-using-sd-card-as-root-disk).

**`sdmmc0: can't enable card`**

Install process starts as usual but when I proceed to disk selection, there are no available disks:

```
Available disks are: .
Which disk is the root disk? ('?' for details)
```

How did I create bootable SD card (by following INSTALL.arm64):

```
dd if=miniroot72.img of=/dev/rsd1c bs=1m
mount /dev/sd1i /mnt
mkdir /mnt/rockchip
cp /usr/local/share/dtb/arm64/rockchip/rk3399-nanopi-r4s.dtb /mnt/rockchip/
umount /mnt

dd if=/usr/local/share/u-boot/nanopi-r4s-rk3399/idbloader.img of=/dev/sd1c seek=64
dd if=/usr/local/share/u-boot/nanopi-r4s-rk3399/u-boot.itb of=/dev/sd1c seek=16384
```

A complete boot process:

```
Channel 0: LPDDR4, 50MHz
BW=32 Col=10 Bk=8 CS0 Row=15 CS1 Row=15 CS=2 Die BW=16 Size=2048MB
Channel 1: LPDDR4, 50MHz
BW=32 Col=10 Bk=8 CS0 Row=15 CS1 Row=15 CS=2 Die BW=16 Size=2048MB
256B stride
lpddr4_set_rate: change freq to 400000000 mhz 0, 1
lpddr4_set_rate: change freq to 800000000 mhz 1, 0
Trying to boot from BOOTROM
Returning to boot ROM...

U-Boot SPL 2021.10 (Sep 29 2022 - 12:11:51 -0600)
Trying to boot from MMC1
NOTICE:  BL31: v2.7(debug):2.7.0
NOTICE:  BL31: Built : 11:58:26, Sep 29 2022
INFO:    GICv3 with legacy support detected.
INFO:    ARM GICv3 driver initialized in EL3
INFO:    Maximum SPI INTID supported: 287
INFO:    plat_rockchip_pmu_init(1625): pd status 3e
INFO:    BL31: Initializing runtime services
INFO:    BL31: cortex_a53: CPU workaround for 855873 was applied
WARNING: BL31: cortex_a53: CPU workaround for 1530924 was missing!
INFO:    BL31: Preparing for EL3 exit to normal world
INFO:    Entry point address = 0x200000
INFO:    SPSR = 0x3c9


U-Boot 2021.10 (Sep 29 2022 - 12:11:51 -0600)

SoC: Rockchip rk3399
Reset cause: POR
Model: FriendlyElec NanoPi R4S
DRAM:  3.9 GiB
PMIC:  RK808
MMC:   mmc@fe320000: 1
Loading Environment from MMC... MMC Device 0 not found
*** Warning - No MMC card found, using default environment

rk3399_vop vop@ff8f0000: failed to get ahb reset (ret=-524)
rk3399_vop vop@ff8f0000: failed to get ahb reset (ret=-524)
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Model: FriendlyElec NanoPi R4S
Net:
Error: ethernet@fe300000 address not set.
No ethernet found.

Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1 is current device
Scanning mmc 1:1...
56978 bytes read in 9 ms (6 MiB/s)
Scanning disk mmc@fe320000.blk...
Found 3 disks
No EFI system partition
rk3399_vop vop@ff8f0000: failed to get ahb reset (ret=-524)
mdio_register: non unique device name 'ethernet@fe300000'
mdio_register: non unique device name 'ethernet@fe300000'
BootOrder not defined
EFI boot manager: Cannot load any image
Found EFI removable media binary efi/boot/bootaa64.efi
208243 bytes read in 17 ms (11.7 MiB/s)
Booting /efi\boot\bootaa64.efi
disks: sd0*
>> OpenBSD/arm64 BOOTAA64 1.12
boot>
cannot open sd0a:/etc/random.seed: No such file or directory
booting sd0a:/bsd: 2737792+1042224+12703464+633568 [228239+91+635880+248536]=0x13c7f78
Copyright (c) 1982, 1986, 1989, 1991, 1993
        The Regents of the University of California.  All rights reserved.
Copyright (c) 1995-2022 OpenBSD. All rights reserved.  https://www.OpenBSD.org

OpenBSD 7.2 (RAMDISK) #1719: Tue Sep 27 16:02:14 MDT 2022
    deraadt@arm64.openbsd.org:/usr/src/sys/arch/arm64/compile/RAMDISK
real mem  = 4038893568 (3851MB)
avail mem = 3835502592 (3657MB)
random: boothowto does not indicate good seed
mainbus0 at root: FriendlyElec NanoPi R4S
psci0 at mainbus0: PSCI 1.1, SMCCC 1.2, SYSTEM_SUSPEND
cpu0 at mainbus0 mpidr 0: ARM Cortex-A53 r0p4
cpu0: 32KB 64b/line 2-way L1 VIPT I-cache, 32KB 64b/line 4-way L1 D-cache
cpu0: 512KB 64b/line 16-way L2 cache
cpu0: CRC32,SHA2,SHA1,AES+PMULL,ASID16
efi0 at mainbus0: UEFI 2.8
efi0: Das U-Boot rev 0x20211000
agintc0 at mainbus0 sec shift 3:3 nirq 288 nredist 6: "interrupt-controller"
agintcmsi0 at agintc0
syscon0 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon1 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon2 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon3 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon4 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon5 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon6 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon7 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon8 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon9 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon10 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon11 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon12 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon13 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon14 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon15 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon16 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon17 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon18 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon19 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon20 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon21 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon22 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon23 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon24 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon25 at mainbus0: "power-management"
"power-controller" at syscon25 not configured
syscon26 at mainbus0: "syscon"
"io-domains" at syscon26 not configured
rkclock0 at mainbus0
rkclock1 at mainbus0
CRU_CLKGATE_CON5: 0x000003e0
CRU_CLKGATE_CON32: 0x00000005
syscon27 at mainbus0: "syscon"
"io-domains" at syscon27 not configured
"usb2phy" at syscon27 not configured
"usb2phy" at syscon27 not configured
"pcie-phy" at syscon27 not configured
rktcphy0 at mainbus0
rktcphy1 at mainbus0
rkpinctrl0 at mainbus0: "pinctrl"
rkgpio0 at rkpinctrl0
rkgpio1 at rkpinctrl0
rkgpio2 at rkpinctrl0
rkgpio3 at rkpinctrl0
rkgpio4 at rkpinctrl0
"pmu_a53" at mainbus0 not configured
"pmu_a72" at mainbus0 not configured
agtimer0 at mainbus0: 24000 kHz
"xin24m" at mainbus0 not configured
rkpcie0 at mainbus0
pci0 at rkpcie0
ppb0 at pci0 dev 0 function 0 "Rockchip RK3399 Root Complex" rev 0x00: msi
pci1 at ppb0 bus 1
re0 at pci1 dev 0 function 0 "Realtek 8168" rev 0x15: RTL8168H/8111H (0x5400), msi, address 00:00:00:00:00:00
rgephy0 at re0 phy 7: RTL8251 PHY, rev. 0
dwge0 at mainbus0: rev 0x35, address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
rgephy1 at dwge0 phy 1: RTL8169S/8110S/8211 PHY, rev. 5
dwmmc0 at mainbus0: 50 MHz base clock
sdmmc0 at dwmmc0: 4-bit, sd high-speed, mmc high-speed, dma
ehci0 at mainbus0
usb0 at ehci0: USB revision 2.0
uhub0 at usb0 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic EHCI root hub" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 1
ohci0 at mainbus0: version 1.0
ehci1 at mainbus0
usb1 at ehci1: USB revision 2.0
uhub1 at usb1 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic EHCI root hub" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 1
ohci1 at mainbus0: version 1.0
rkdwusb0 at mainbus0: "usb"
xhci0 at rkdwusb0, xHCI 1.10
usb2 at xhci0: USB revision 3.0
uhub2 at usb2 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic xHCI root hub" rev 3.00/1.00 addr 1
rkdwusb1 at mainbus0: "usb"
xhci1 at rkdwusb1, xHCI 1.10
usb3 at xhci1: USB revision 3.0
uhub3 at usb3 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic xHCI root hub" rev 3.00/1.00 addr 1
"saradc" at mainbus0 not configured
rkiic0 at mainbus0
iic0 at rkiic0
rkiic1 at mainbus0
iic1 at rkiic1
rkiic2 at mainbus0
iic2 at rkiic2
com0 at mainbus0: dw16550, 64 byte fifo
com0: console
"tsadc" at mainbus0 not configured
rkrng0 at mainbus0
rkiic3 at mainbus0
iic3 at rkiic3
"silergy,syr827" at iic3 addr 0x40 not configured
"silergy,syr828" at iic3 addr 0x41 not configured
rkpmic0 at iic3 addr 0x1b: RK808
rkpwm0 at mainbus0
rkpwm1 at mainbus0
rkpwm2 at mainbus0
"video-codec" at mainbus0 not configured
"iommu" at mainbus0 not configured
"video-codec" at mainbus0 not configured
"iommu" at mainbus0 not configured
"rga" at mainbus0 not configured
"efuse" at mainbus0 not configured
"dma-controller" at mainbus0 not configured
"dma-controller" at mainbus0 not configured
"watchdog" at mainbus0 not configured
"rktimer" at mainbus0 not configured
"i2s" at mainbus0 not configured
"vop" at mainbus0 not configured
"iommu" at mainbus0 not configured
"vop" at mainbus0 not configured
"iommu" at mainbus0 not configured
"iommu" at mainbus0 not configured
"iommu" at mainbus0 not configured
"hdmi-sound" at mainbus0 not configured
"hdmi" at mainbus0 not configured
"gpu" at mainbus0 not configured
"opp-table0" at mainbus0 not configured
"opp-table1" at mainbus0 not configured
"opp-table2" at mainbus0 not configured
"external-gmac-clock" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcc3v3-sys" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcc5v0-sys" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcc1v8-s3" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcc3v0-sd" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcca0v9-s3" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcca1v8-s3" at mainbus0 not configured
"vbus-typec" at mainbus0 not configured
"gpio-keys" at mainbus0 not configured
"gpio-leds" at mainbus0 not configured
"sdio-pwrseq" at mainbus0 not configured
"vdd-5v" at mainbus0 not configured
usb4 at ohci0: USB revision 1.0
uhub4 at usb4 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic OHCI root hub" rev 1.00/1.00 addr 1
usb5 at ohci1: USB revision 1.0
uhub5 at usb5 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic OHCI root hub" rev 1.00/1.00 addr 1
sdmmc0: can't enable card
softraid0 at root
scsibus0 at softraid0: 256 targets
root on rd0a swap on rd0b dump on rd0b
WARNING: bad clock chip time
WARNING: CHECK AND RESET THE DATE!
erase ^?, werase ^W, kill ^U, intr ^C, status ^T

Welcome to the OpenBSD/arm64 7.2 installation program.
```

These lines also got my attention:

```
Loading Environment from MMC... MMC Device 0 not found
*** Warning - No MMC card found, using default environment
```

Is there anybody who can help me with this issue? I do not have a large knowledge of U-boot but this appears to me to be a problem with OpenBSD.
Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:**

1. I have repeated the process with a different SD card with the same result.
2. armbian works well with the same SD card on the same hardware with the following dmesg

```
$ cat armbian_dmesg.txt | grep -i mmc
[    2.157778] dwmmc_rockchip fe320000.mmc: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
[    2.157817] dwmmc_rockchip fe320000.mmc: Using internal DMA controller.
[    2.157833] dwmmc_rockchip fe320000.mmc: Version ID is 270a
[    2.157898] dwmmc_rockchip fe320000.mmc: DW MMC controller at irq 32,32 bit host data width,256 deep fifo
[    2.158479] dwmmc_rockchip fe320000.mmc: Got CD GPIO
[    2.171628] mmc_host mmc1: Bus speed (slot 0) = 400000Hz (slot req 400000Hz, actual 400000HZ div = 0)
[    2.222212] mmc_host mmc1: Bus speed (slot 0) = 50000000Hz (slot req 50000000Hz, actual 50000000HZ div = 0)
[    2.222327] mmc1: new high speed SDHC card at address 59b4
[    2.223491] mmcblk1: mmc1:59b4 SMI   29.1 GiB
[    2.226955]  mmcblk1: p1
[    5.992879] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p1): mounted filesystem with writeback data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    8.259026] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p1): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600,errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
```

**Edit 2:**
I have found the following dmesg of OpenBSD 6.9 on nanopi-r4s-rk3399 in OpenBSD ports [mail-archive](https://www.mail-archive.com/ports@openbsd.org/msg106067.html):

```
OpenBSD 6.9-current (GENERIC.MP) #1274: Wed Aug  4 13:54:03 MDT 2021
    deraadt@arm64.openbsd.org:/usr/src/sys/arch/arm64/compile/GENERIC.MP
real mem  = 4038881280 (3851MB)
avail mem = 3839676416 (3661MB)
random: good seed from bootblocks
mainbus0 at root: FriendlyElec NanoPi R4S
psci0 at mainbus0: PSCI 1.1, SMCCC 1.2
cpu0 at mainbus0 mpidr 0: ARM Cortex-A53 r0p4
cpu0: 32KB 64b/line 2-way L1 VIPT I-cache, 32KB 64b/line 4-way L1 D-cache
cpu0: 512KB 64b/line 16-way L2 cache
cpu0: CRC32,SHA2,SHA1,AES+PMULL,ASID16
cpu1 at mainbus0 mpidr 1: ARM Cortex-A53 r0p4
cpu1: 32KB 64b/line 2-way L1 VIPT I-cache, 32KB 64b/line 4-way L1 D-cache
cpu1: 512KB 64b/line 16-way L2 cache
cpu1: CRC32,SHA2,SHA1,AES+PMULL,ASID16
cpu2 at mainbus0 mpidr 2: ARM Cortex-A53 r0p4
cpu2: 32KB 64b/line 2-way L1 VIPT I-cache, 32KB 64b/line 4-way L1 D-cache
cpu2: 512KB 64b/line 16-way L2 cache
cpu2: CRC32,SHA2,SHA1,AES+PMULL,ASID16
cpu3 at mainbus0 mpidr 3: ARM Cortex-A53 r0p4
cpu3: 32KB 64b/line 2-way L1 VIPT I-cache, 32KB 64b/line 4-way L1 D-cache
cpu3: 512KB 64b/line 16-way L2 cache
cpu3: CRC32,SHA2,SHA1,AES+PMULL,ASID16
cpu4 at mainbus0 mpidr 100: ARM Cortex-A72 r0p2
cpu4: 48KB 64b/line 3-way L1 PIPT I-cache, 32KB 64b/line 2-way L1 D-cache
cpu4: 1024KB 64b/line 16-way L2 cache
cpu4: CRC32,SHA2,SHA1,AES+PMULL,ASID16
cpu5 at mainbus0 mpidr 101: ARM Cortex-A72 r0p2
cpu5: 48KB 64b/line 3-way L1 PIPT I-cache, 32KB 64b/line 2-way L1 D-cache
cpu5: 1024KB 64b/line 16-way L2 cache
cpu5: CRC32,SHA2,SHA1,AES+PMULL,ASID16
efi0 at mainbus0: UEFI 2.8
efi0: Das U-Boot rev 0x20210700
apm0 at mainbus0
agintc0 at mainbus0 sec shift 3:3 nirq 288 nredist 6 ipi: 0, 1: "interrupt-controller"
agintcmsi0 at agintc0
syscon0 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon1 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon2 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon3 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon4 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon5 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon6 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon7 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon8 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon9 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon10 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon11 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon12 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon13 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon14 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon15 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon16 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon17 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon18 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon19 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon20 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon21 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon22 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon23 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon24 at mainbus0: "qos"
syscon25 at mainbus0: "power-management"
"power-controller" at syscon25 not configured
syscon26 at mainbus0: "syscon"
"io-domains" at syscon26 not configured
rkclock0 at mainbus0
rkclock1 at mainbus0
CRU_CLKGATE_CON5: 0x000003e0
CRU_CLKGATE_CON32: 0x00000005
syscon27 at mainbus0: "syscon"
"io-domains" at syscon27 not configured
"usb2-phy" at syscon27 not configured
"usb2-phy" at syscon27 not configured
"pcie-phy" at syscon27 not configured
rktcphy0 at mainbus0
rktcphy1 at mainbus0
rkpinctrl0 at mainbus0: "pinctrl"
rkgpio0 at rkpinctrl0
rkgpio1 at rkpinctrl0
rkgpio2 at rkpinctrl0
rkgpio3 at rkpinctrl0
rkgpio4 at rkpinctrl0
syscon28 at mainbus0: "syscon"
syscon29 at mainbus0: "syscon"
"fit-images" at mainbus0 not configured
rkdrm0 at mainbus0
drm0 at rkdrm0
"pmu_a53" at mainbus0 not configured
"pmu_a72" at mainbus0 not configured
agtimer0 at mainbus0: 24000 kHz
"xin24m" at mainbus0 not configured
simplebus0 at mainbus0: "bus"
"dma-controller" at simplebus0 not configured
"dma-controller" at simplebus0 not configured
rkpcie0 at mainbus0
pci0 at rkpcie0
ppb0 at pci0 dev 0 function 0 "Rockchip RK3399 Root Complex" rev 0x00: msi
pci1 at ppb0 bus 1
re0 at pci1 dev 0 function 0 "Realtek 8168" rev 0x15: RTL8168H/8111H (0x5400), msi, address 00:00:00:00:00:00
rgephy0 at re0 phy 7: RTL8251 PHY, rev. 0
dwge0 at mainbus0: rev 0x35, address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
rgephy1 at dwge0 phy 1: RTL8169S/8110S/8211 PHY, rev. 5
dwmmc0 at mainbus0: 50 MHz base clock
sdmmc0 at dwmmc0: 4-bit, sd high-speed, mmc high-speed, dma
ehci0 at mainbus0
usb0 at ehci0: USB revision 2.0
uhub0 at usb0 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic EHCI root hub" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 1
ohci0 at mainbus0: version 1.0
ehci1 at mainbus0
usb1 at ehci1: USB revision 2.0
uhub1 at usb1 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic EHCI root hub" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 1
ohci1 at mainbus0: version 1.0
rkdwusb0 at mainbus0: "usb"
xhci0 at rkdwusb0, xHCI 1.10
usb2 at xhci0: USB revision 3.0
uhub2 at usb2 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic xHCI root hub" rev 3.00/1.00 addr 1
rkdwusb1 at mainbus0: "usb"
xhci1 at rkdwusb1, xHCI 1.10
usb3 at xhci1: USB revision 3.0
uhub3 at usb3 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic xHCI root hub" rev 3.00/1.00 addr 1
"saradc" at mainbus0 not configured
rkiic0 at mainbus0
iic0 at rkiic0
rkiic1 at mainbus0
iic1 at rkiic1
rkiic2 at mainbus0
iic2 at rkiic2
com0 at mainbus0: ns16550, no working fifo
com1 at mainbus0: ns16550, no working fifo
com1: console
rktemp0 at mainbus0
rkiic3 at mainbus0
iic3 at rkiic3
fanpwr0 at iic3 addr 0x40: SYR827, 0.80 VDC
fanpwr1 at iic3 addr 0x41: SYR828, 1.00 VDC
rkpmic0 at iic3 addr 0x1b: RK808
rkiic4 at mainbus0
iic4 at rkiic4
rkpwm0 at mainbus0
rkpwm1 at mainbus0
rkpwm2 at mainbus0
"video-codec" at mainbus0 not configured
"iommu" at mainbus0 not configured
"rga" at mainbus0 not configured
"efuse" at mainbus0 not configured
"watchdog" at mainbus0 not configured
"rktimer" at mainbus0 not configured
rkiis0 at mainbus0
rkvop0 at mainbus0: RK3399 VOPL
"iommu" at mainbus0 not configured
rkvop1 at mainbus0: RK3399 VOPB
"iommu" at mainbus0 not configured
"iommu" at mainbus0 not configured
"iommu" at mainbus0 not configured
simpleaudio0 at mainbus0
rkdwhdmi0 at mainbus0: HDMI TX
rkdwhdmi0: version 2.11a, phytype 0xf3
"gpu" at mainbus0 not configured
"opp-table0" at mainbus0 not configured
"opp-table1" at mainbus0 not configured
"opp-table2" at mainbus0 not configured
"external-gmac-clock" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcc3v3-sys" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcc5v0-sys" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcc1v8-s3" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcc3v0-sd" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcca0v9-s3" at mainbus0 not configured
"vcca1v8-s3" at mainbus0 not configured
"vbus-typec" at mainbus0 not configured
"gpio-keys" at mainbus0 not configured
"gpio-leds" at mainbus0 not configured
"sdio-pwrseq" at mainbus0 not configured
"vdd-5v" at mainbus0 not configured
pwmfan0 at mainbus0
"binman" at mainbus0 not configured
"dfi" at mainbus0 not configured
rkrng0 at mainbus0
"dmc" at mainbus0 not configured
usb4 at ohci0: USB revision 1.0
uhub4 at usb4 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic OHCI root hub" rev 1.00/1.00 addr 1
usb5 at ohci1: USB revision 1.0
uhub5 at usb5 configuration 1 interface 0 "Generic OHCI root hub" rev 1.00/1.00 addr 1
dt: 445 probes
scsibus0 at sdmmc0: 2 targets, initiator 0
sd0 at scsibus0 targ 1 lun 0: <SD/MMC, SC16G, 0080> removable
sd0: 15193MB, 512 bytes/sector, 31116288 sectors
umass0 at uhub3 port 2 configuration 1 interface 0 "USB SanDisk 3.2Gen1" rev 3.00/1.00 addr 2
umass0: using SCSI over Bulk-Only
scsibus1 at umass0: 2 targets, initiator 0
sd1 at scsibus1 targ 1 lun 0: <USB, SanDisk 3.2Gen1, 1.00> removable serial.07815583810715aa585e
sd1: 14664MB, 512 bytes/sector, 30031872 sectors
vscsi0 at root
scsibus2 at vscsi0: 256 targets
softraid0 at root
scsibus3 at softraid0: 256 targets
root on sd1a (e816847591eab340.a) swap on sd1b dump on sd1b
rkvop0: using CRTC 0 for RK3399 VOPL
rkvop1: using CRTC 1 for RK3399 VOPB
rkdrm0: 1024x768, 32bpp
wsdisplay0 at rkdrm0 mux 1
wsdisplay0: screen 0-5 added (std, vt100 emulation)
```

MMC seems to work there:

```
dwmmc0 at mainbus0: 50 MHz base clock
sdmmc0 at dwmmc0: 4-bit, sd high-speed, mmc high-speed, dma
...
scsibus0 at sdmmc0: 2 targets, initiator 0
sd0 at scsibus0 targ 1 lun 0: <SD/MMC, SC16G, 0080> removable
sd0: 15193MB, 512 bytes/sector, 31116288 sectors
```